# Used Wshttpsbinding of WCF-custom Adapter in the send ports.Getting Multiple headers with name 'NotUnderstood'

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, wcf-wshttpbinding

Below are the configuration details:

[image: SOAP Action:]

[image]

Error Details:

> A message sent to adapter "WCF-Custom" on send port "SendSIMONMessage" with URI "https://simon-qa.dhec.sc.gov/hl7engine_qa/CDC/V1/IISService.svc" is suspended.
> Error details: System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderException: Multiple headers with name 'NotUnderstood' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' found.
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeaders.FindNonAddressingHeader(String name, String ns, String[] actors)
> at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfMarshaller.CopyHeadersToContext(Message wcfMessage, IBaseMessageContext btsMessageContext)
> at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfMarshaller.CreateBizTalkMessage(IBaseMessageFactory messageFactory, IAdapterConfigInboundMessageMarshalling marshallingConfig, Message wcfMessage, TLConfig tlConfig, RLConfig rlConfig)
> at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)
> MessageId:  {53B82908-5706-4132-8FE6-0A2EC68D80DC}
> InstanceID: {A2072008-0388-4B4C-B25E-A8D73274EBE3}

Can some one please help?

Comment: Hi Arupa.  It looks like the API may be throwing back an error.  To capture that, set the Receive Pipeline to PassThru, and then look at what you are getting back.  Or use something like FIddler to capture the payload.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you r using WShttpBinding for? For WshttpBinding, service should support WS* protocols. If you r just looking for SSL, use BasicHttpBinding with appropriate security

Comment: @VikasBhardwaj - The service that we are consuming supports only SOAP 1.2. That is the reason we have opted for WShttpBindings. Can we achieve the same using BasichttpBinding?? If yes could you please guide us or give some references. Adding to this the binding file that we have received has "custombindings" , can you suggest what binding we can use for this

Comment: @Dijkgraaf we have mentioned Passthru in receive pipeline, we are getting the same error as mentioned above. but when we tried to post the same message using SOAP UI we are getting authorization issue. Could that be a reason for the error message?

Comment: For SOAP you need to use the BasicHttp binding, or use the WCF-BasicHttp Adapter.  It might be easier to try the adapter first.

Answer (score 0):

You should use customBinding on WCF-Custom send port for Soap12. Within customBinding, Change following property textMessageEncoding->messageVersion to Soap12. You should also generate binding file using service wsdl by using [Consume WCF Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-use-the-biztalk-wcf-service-consuming-wizard-to-consume-a-wcf-service) wizard. it should generate appropriate binding to use. You don't have to use generated orchestration depending on your design